# Differentiate $\ln\left( x^ {x^2} \right)$ without product or quotient rule

Tags: calculus, derivatives, logarithms, exponential-function

Differentiate $$\ln\left( x^ {x^2} \right)$$ without product or quotient rule. I want to see how this can be differentiated without bringing down $x^2$ and using the product rule.

I am getting the following answer, I can’t see an problems with my steps but my answer is still wrong
[image]

Comment: Looks like you have applied the power rule when the power in question is not constant! What is your objection to "bringing down" $x^2$?

Comment: @FShrike I don’t understand why my steps have  have nothing to do with the definition of derivative’. I have only used the power, chain rule and derivative of ln x

Comment: Please do not use images to convey key information about your question. [Here is a good explanation why you should not](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/34123/742).Learn to use MathJax instead.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are using the 'rule':
$$ \frac{d}{dx} x^{u(x)} = u(x) \cdot x^{u(x) - 1}, $$
confusing this more complicated situation with the 'power rule':
$$ \frac{d}{dx} x^n = n \cdot x^{n-1}. $$
The reason the answer is wrong is that you've done something that simply doesn't work.

Comment: So ur saying I can only use the power rule when a constant is the exponent, and I can’t use it when a function is an exponent ? If that’s the case then what is the reason for this

Comment: @aaksaksyk Consider $e^x$. What would happen if you applied your "power rule" here? You see a problem?

Comment: @Golden_Ratio that example helped my understanding but I actually don’t know why we can’t use the power rule to differentiate e^x

Comment: @aaksaksyk Perhaps it would be instructive to see the proof of where the power rule comes from. It relies on the power being a constant. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_rule#Proofs

Comment: @Golden_Ratio I saw the binomial theorem proof for the power rule and that doesn’t seem to be imply that the exponent has to be constant

Comment: @aaksaksyk That proof would not go through if the power was not a natural number. Note that if the power was variable (and thus allowed to be irrational), there would be infinitely many terms in the binomial expansion since you would have to use Newton's generalized binomial theorem: https://www.whitman.edu/mathematics/cgt_online/book/section03.01.html

Comment: @aaksaksyk Not to mention the computation would also be different; the numerator of the difference quotient would be $(x+h)^{n(x+h)}-x^{n(x)}$ where $n(x)$ is the power as a function of $x$

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is the *generalized power rule*, which is rarely taught today.  The power rule and the exponentiation rule are just both simplifications of the generalized power rule that occur when either the base or the exponent is constant.  The generalized power rule is:

$$d(q^r) = r\,q^{r - 1}\,dq + \ln(q)\,q^r\, dr$$

Now, the differential of a constant is zero.  So, if you have an "ordinary" power rule (where the power is constant), the $dr$ is the differential of a constant, and therefore zero.  If you have an exponent rule, where the base is constant, then $dq$ is zero.

Unfortunately, the generalized power rule is rarely taught.

Using the generalized power rule, you get:

$$ u = x^{x^2} \\
d(\ln(u)) = \frac{du}{u} \\
du = d\left(x^{x^2}\right) \\
w = x^2 \\
dw = 2x\,dx \\
du = d\left(x^w\right) \\
du = wx^{w-1}\,dx + \ln(x)x^w\,dw \\
du = x^2\,x^{x^2 - 1}\,dx + 2x\,\ln(x)x^{x^2}\,dx \\
\frac{d}{dx}\left(\ln\left(x^{x^2}\right)\right) = \frac{x^2\,x^{x^2 - 1}\,dx + 2x\,\ln(x)x^{x^2}\,dx}{x^{x^2}\,dx} \\
 = \frac{x^2\,x^{x^2 - 1} + 2x\,\ln(x)x^{x^2}}{x^{x^2}} \\
 = x + 2x\,\ln(x) $$

A commenter said that a justification of the rule would be helpful.  However, the *justification* for the rule involves the product rule.  However, the rule itself can be learned/applied without it.

So, the rule to be established is the rule for $d(q^r)$.  So, let us start with $z = q^r$.  Ultimately, the goal is to find $dz$, which will be equivalent to $d(q^r)$:

$$ z = q^r \\
\ln(z) = \ln(q^r) \\
\ln(z) = r \ln(q) \\
d(\ln(z)) = d(r\ln(q)) \\
\frac{dz}{z} = \frac{r}{q}\,dq + \ln(q)\,dr \\
dz = \frac{rz}{q}\,dq + \ln(q)\,z\,dr
dz = \frac{r\,q^r}{q}\,dq + \ln(q)\,q^r\,dr \\
dz = r\,q^{r - 1}\,dq + \ln(q)\,q^r\,dr $$

So, essentially, we are using the natural log to convert an exponent into a multiplication, so then we can use the product rule during differentiation, then we solve for $dz$.

Comment: and for good reason the rule isn't taught, since it's not worth memorizing (though you obviously disagree with this opinion). Anyway, as written, this leaves a lot unanswered: why can one just add the two changes (multivariable chain rule), and why the second term is the way it is (the crux being the definition of powers $q^r:= e^{r\log q}$ for $q>0$ and $r\in\Bbb{R}$). So, as written you haven't addressed OP's misunderstanding

Comment: If you are interested in the generalized power rule, it is taught in my book, "Calculus from the Ground Up".

Comment: I think showing how some formula A is a simplification of a broader formula B under certain circumstances *is* addressing such misunderstandings.

I also don't see why this wouldn't be worth memorizing.  You literally get one rule instead of three (power, exponent, and logarithmic differentiation), and, differentiation becomes wholly mechanical (without the rule you have to manipulate the formula before differentiating).

Comment: seems like you just edited to address OP's question directly, so ignore the final sentence of my previous comment. As for why it's not worth memorizing, first of all, the formula you've written down doesn't belong in single-variable calculus; also you just stated that formula without any explanation of why it is the way it is, which is clearly unhelpful. Yes, you get one rule, but only because you combined three of them into one with the multivariable chain rule. Next, formulas like these are easily misremembered. Also, there's the saying: "give a man a fish..."

Comment: Anyway, my intent is not to argue about the merits of memorizing various equations, since this is clearly a subjective matter (some people can just memorize better than others), rather my main issue is that you didn't justify or even point to a reference for where the formula for differentiating exponents comes from.

Answer (score 0):

Let $u = \ln \left( x^{x^2} \right) = x^2 \ln \left( x \right)$

Apply logarithm: $\ln u = \ln \left( x^2 \ln x \right)$

Rewrite product in logarithm as the sum of logarithms: $\ln u = \ln \left( x^2 \right) + \ln ( \ln x )$

Apply exponentiation: $u = e^{\ln \left( x^2 \right) + \ln ( \ln x )} = e^{2 \ln x + \ln ( \ln x )}$

Differentiate. Use the chain rule to differentiate the argument inside $e^x$. Use the chain rule again to differentiate $\ln ( \ln x )$.

$u' = \left( \frac{2}{x} + \frac{1}{x \ln x} \right) e^{2 \ln x + \ln ( \ln x )}$

The strategy is essentially just using logarithms to convert multiplication operations into addition operations to avoid using the product or quotient rules.